# Multiple IN operator sql

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have 3 list and I want to fetch result from db based on these three list.

```
select * 
from user_detail
where email_address in ('abc@test.com', 'def@test.com', 'ghi@test.com') 
  and city in ('delhi', 'bangalore') 
  and zip_code in ('11000', '12345', '45678');
```

Is this a good approach and will the result be accurate ?

any one please suggest me if any better approach for this scenario.

Comment: no reason that shouldn't work

Comment: Hi paul , I am only worried about one thing here, Is it ok to use three in list operator. Can you please help me out understanding how this three in list operator will behave?

Comment: the "in" operators are separated by AND, so it will treat them like any other conditions connected by AND, requiring all three to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the result will be accurate... but what is generating the list ?

If you are just trying to retrieve data based off 3 large lists... then use tables.

```
select * from user_detail 

inner join emails on emails.email_address = user_detail.email_address
inner join cities on cities.city = user_detail.city
inner join zip_codes on zips_codes.zip_codes = user_detail.zip_code
```

If it's a query based on user input.. then what you have would be the method.

Comment: its based on user input , but I am worried about is it ok to use three in list operator ? how this three in list operator will behave in this scenario?